# Total derivative multivariate chain rule application

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a function  $\phi(x(a,b(a)))$, and I am looking for its total derivative with respect to $a$. My best understanding of applying the multivariate chain rule is

\begin{align}
\frac{d \phi}{d a} &= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d a} \\
&= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial x}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial a} \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} +  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial a} 
\end{align}

but the last line looks a little weird to me due to the triple partial derivative. Of course I've got the triple nested function, but I'm wondering if I have missed any partial derivatives and/or my notation is sloppy. Thanks for any comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems right, although I would use $\frac{db}{da}$ instead of $\frac{\partial b}{\partial a}$ the last lines. Also I would use the term "full derivative" instead of "total derivative", to avoid confusion with the map $D\phi$ used in multivariable analysis.

Comment: Many thanks. These are good suggestions.